# Syntax error while creating trigger on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger in phpmyadmin but I keep getting an error. Can someone help me on what is wrong?

Here is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumOfRecords
AFTER INSERT ON recording
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE poem
SET NumRecordings = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recording WHERE poem.PoemTitle = recording.PoemTitle)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

*1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6*

Comment: And what does this have to do with `java`?

Comment: Also there is no connection to `phpmyadmin`. This is simply a `mysql` question.

Comment: @arkascha I have created all my tables and data etc. with java within netbeans so my trigger will be created in java also but I just wanted to test it first on phpmyadmin. I use a driver to connect my database to phpmyadmin and use localhost to view the data

Comment: That is all fine. But you also used a notebook (or whatever computer) to do that. Still you did not tag this question "notebook". What I am saying is: the issue at hand is a mysql issue. The error message clearly says so. So the other tools involved are irrelevant.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry about that, my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: All fine, welcome! Just use the `edit` link below your question and remove those tags ;-)